# XPages ratio between 2 column totals in view

Tags: view, xpages

I have a view with 2 columns. Both number types. I want to add a button to the page, which will **calculate the ration between total of column 1 and total of column 2.**

```
For example:
Column 1 | Column 2
5        | 5
10       | 10
4        | 3
3        | 4
It should be (5+10+4+3)/(5+10+3+4) = 1..
```

Thank you,

Florin

Comment: Thanks for the edit to the question Krupa.  Nice job!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go into the view properties and turn on the totals for both those columns.  Then in SSJS I'd get a NotesNavigator for that view and then create a NotesViewEntry object.  Then I'd set that ViewEntry to the NotesNavigator.getLastEntry()...  something like that.  That entry should then have a columnValues() property.  I THINK it would be something like:

```
var column1 = entry.getColumnValues()[1];
var column2 = entry.getColumnValues()[2];
```

Note: getColumnValues() is zero based and depending on the view design some columns might not be available to retrieve from getColumnValues().

Once you have you're 2 var's then you can do the math and do whatever with the result.

That's how I would approach it at least.

(I don't have an editor handy so sorry if some of the syntax is off)

Comment: Since you will have your view categorized when you turn on the totals I know there is a view entry option for something like isCategory() and almost positive there is an option for isTotal() that can be used.  Just an alternative to what David has suggested