# Xpages view string type ratio

Tags: view, time, xpages

I have a view with 2 columns, both type of String. One is always "08:00" and one depends on the user input. It could be 02:30 or 13:45, etc...

I want to convert all the column of 08:00's and all the other column of values, add them together and then divide the total...

Example:

```
Column 1 | Column 2
02:50    | 08:00
05:15    | 08:00
15:25    | 08:00
03:15    | 08:00
```

It would be something like:(~26)/(8*4)=~0.8%.
It's a timekeeping application. I have the normal-time of 8 hours and the time the employee worked, and I want to add a button that will calculate the ratio between the 2 columns.

Thank you,

Florin

Comment: Didn't we have that lately? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483571/xpages-ratio-between-2-column-totals-in-view

Comment: I made an error... My column are type of string not number... This is why I created another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I used to calculate the ration between 2 columns of strings:

```
var vec:NotesViewEntryCollection = viewSearch.getAllEntries();
var c = vec.getCount()
var data = @DbColumn(@DbName(),"vwSearch",4);

var totalH = 0;
var totalM = 0;

for(var i=0;i<c;i++){
var str = data[i].toString();
var a = str.split(":",2)[0];
var b = str.split(":",2)[1]; 
var hour = parseInt(a);
var minutes = parseInt(b);
totalH += hour;
totalM += minutes;

if(totalM >= 60)
{
    totalH++;
    totalM-=60;
}
}

var h_necesare = c*8;

getComponent("h_lucrate").setValue(totalH+" ore, si "+totalM+" minute.");
getComponent("h_necesare").setValue(h_necesare);
getComponent("raport").setValue(totalH-h_necesare);
```

Comment: Florin,  Did this code work for you?  If so you should make it as the answer.